# Optional overloaded methods when overriding

Tags: java, class, overriding, overloading, abstract

Case :

I have an abstract class A. It contains two methods

1. `abstract void search(Position p);`
2. `abstract void search(Animal a);`

Class B and C extends A. I would like class B to implement `search(Position p)` only and class C to implement `search(Animal a)` only. However when I do so it gives an error, telling me to implement both of the method overloads.

How could I solve the problem? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You can't do that. Every concrete class that extends `A` **must** provide implementations of **both** `abstract` methods. Any class which didn't, wouldn't be an `A`. So the compiler won't let you.

Comment: What are you expecting code which calls `A.search(Animal a)` to do when it is called on an instance of `B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the rules for classes extending Abstract class

1. First concrete/non-abstract class must implement all methods
2. If abstract class extends Abstract class, it can but need not implement
   abstract methods.

Option 1: Interface Segregation

```
separate search(XXX) into two abstract classes
```

Option 2: Generics. Make search a Generic Type

```
public abstract class ClassA {

    public abstract <T> void search(T t);

    public static void main(String ...args){
        ClassA classA = new ClassB();
        classA.search(new Animal());
    }
}

class Animal{

}

class ClassB extends ClassA {

    @Override
    public <Animal> void search(Animal t) {
     System.out.println("called");
    }
}
```

Option 3: Interface

```
public class ClassA {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Searchable classA = new ClassB();
        classA.search(new Animal());
    }
}

interface Searchable {
    public <T> void search(T t);
}

class Animal {
}

class ClassB implements Searchable {
    @Override
    public <Animal> void search(Animal t) {
        System.out.println("called");
    }
}
```

Option 4: Throw UnsupportedOperationException Exception(Not recomended)

```
class ClassB extends ClassA {

    @Override
    void search(Position p) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not Supported");
    }

    @Override
    void search(Animal a) {

    }
}
```